# What is the return value of the given function on encountering an exception?

Tags: c++, c++11

`checkUsername()` checks the username's length, and returns `true` when length is greater than or equal to 5. Otherwise it returns `false`. 
The function `checkUsername()` should return false on `BadLengthException()`, but it doesn't seem to appear as none of the code within `checkUsername()` and `BadLengthException::what()` returns `false`. But still the program is working fine when it encounters a username of length less than 5. What's going on here? How is the return value passed `false`?

```
class BadLengthException: public exception{
    public:
        int n;
        BadLengthException(int x) { n=x; };
        virtual int what() throw() {
            return n;
        }
    };
/*
This function checks the username's length, 
and returns true when length is greater than or equal to 5.
Otherwise it returns false.
*/
bool checkUsername(string username) {
    bool isValid = true;
    int n = username.length();
    if(n < 5) {
        throw BadLengthException(n);    //the problem
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        if(username[i] == 'w' && username[i+1] == 'w') {
            isValid = false;
        }
    }
    return isValid;
}

int main() {
    int T; cin >> T;
    while(T--) {
        string username;
        cin >> username;
        try {
            bool isValid = checkUsername(username);
            if(isValid) {
                cout << "Valid" << '\n';
            } else {
                cout << "Invalid" << '\n';
            }
        } catch (BadLengthException e) {
            cout << "Too short: " << e.what() << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When a function throws an exception, the function can't return a value, as it threw an exception. The exception is catched. I don't really understand what you are confused about. Please explain, thanks :)

Comment: And start using the `override` keyword to avoid such mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function can either return a value or throw an exception, it can't do both, they're mutually exclusive. If it successfully returns a value that means the code didn't throw an exception, and if an exception was thrown then it means it didn't make it to the point of returning a value.

Further to that, capturing the return value is also interrupted, the code jumps right to the `catch` block you've defined. It's like a hard `goto` in concept, if you ignore things like automatic object destruction and `finally` type implementations which will happen in the process of an exception bubbling up.

Comment: @Quentin I'm just simplifying how this works and skipping over that part, though I mentioned it since the C++ community here is quick to interject if something's been omitted. To get into all of that is like another six paragraphs of why, how, and when.

Comment: Oh, no, those aren't skipped at all. I'm just omitting those details it for the sake of simplicity. That's  also why I said specifically "`finally` type implementations" as some people strive to emulate that sort of thing in C++ for various reasons. You're right that it could be interpreted that way, so I've changed the phrasing to make that easier to understand.

Comment: Not at all! Once I read it your way I realized it was saying the opposite of what I intended.

Answer (score 1):

When the exception is thrown in `checkUsername()`, it stops processing in that function and returns to the calling function which is `main()`.  Because the call was made in a `try` block the exception is handled by the `catch` block.

The `if()` statement is completely ignored and the `catch` doesn't care about what happened in that function and just prints "Too short: "

Comment: Thanks, for the help  :)